# Uniform convergence for non-negative, continuous $f_n$ on a closed, bounded interval.

Tags: real-analysis

If I have $f_n(x)=\frac{g(x)}{n^2}$, where $g(x)\geq0$ and continuous on an interval $[a,b]$, then I know that $f_n\downarrow 0$. By Dini's Theorem, we know that this convergence is uniform, but is there not an easier (more intuitive) way to prove this, at least with non-negative functions? Why can't we use Extreme Value Theorem to say there is a $c\in[a,b]$ such that $g(c)=M\geq g(x)$ $\forall x\in [a,b]$, so we can find an $N$ such that $\frac{g(x)}{N^2}\leq\frac{M}{N^2}<\epsilon,$ which implies $N>\sqrt{\frac{M}{\epsilon}}.$ This convergence would be uniform, would it not?

Comment: Yes, the alternative solution you gave is also corrext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, also, whether or not the continuous function $g$ is non-negative, we still can perform like $|f_{n}(x)|\leq\dfrac{|g(x)|}{n^{2}}\leq\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\max_{x\in[a,b]}|g(x)|$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are absolutely right! What you showed is essentially

\begin{equation}
\lVert f_n \rVert_{C[a,b]} = \sup\limits_{x \in [a,b]} \lvert f_n(x) \rvert \le \frac{1}{n^2} \sup\limits_{x \in [a,b]} \lvert g(x) \rvert \le \frac{M}{n^2}
\end{equation}

and hence

\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \lVert f_n \rVert_{C[a,b]} = 0
\end{equation}

which is exactly the statement of uniform convergence.

Comment: While this shows that the sequence converges uniformly, it also shows that $f_n\downarrow 0$, yes? Or is more motivation needed to show that.